# UITabBarController with UINavigationController in UISplitViewController breaks status bar

Tags: ios, ipad, ios11

When adding a UINavigationController to a UITabBarController in a UISplitViewController, on an iPad running iOS 11, the status bar does now show the navigation bar.

Sample Code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let t1 = Test2ViewController.init(nibName: "Test2ViewController", bundle: nil)
    t1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    let t1nvc = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: t1)

    let tbc = UITabBarController.init()
    tbc.viewControllers = [t1nvc]

    let t2 = Test2ViewController.init(nibName: "Test2ViewController", bundle: nil)
    t2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    let splitView = UISplitViewController()
    splitView.viewControllers = [tbc, t2]
    self.window!.rootViewController = splitView;
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Phone View [iOS 11]:

*This looks correct

[image: Phone View [iOS 11]]

iPad View [iOS 11]:

*Notice the status bar

[image: iPad View [iOS 11]]

iPad View [iOS 10.3]:

*The status bar looks correct

[image: iPad View [iOS 10.3]]

Comment: Have you tried running this project on a real iPad device?

Comment: Yes, same erroneous condition occurs on the real iPad device running iOS 11.

Comment: I suspect this issue is because of iOS11 fix height(44) of Navigation bar? If you can just confirm this navigation bar height in both iOS 11 and iOS10 devices? If you don't find any solution for this then I can suggest one fix for this which will perfectly work. Let me know.